# SonarQube for Gradle: Component can't be null

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to use SonarQube on a Gradle multiproject. I can't figure out what's going on!

- The sonarqube gradle plugin version is 2.5 and talks to a gradle server 6.5 via token. I've verified that they talk to one another.
- Gradle project compiles nomally, jacoco succesfully converages all code for all subprojects too.

Any pointers much appreciated. The stacktrace:

```
[rubin@eve adhub (issues/SAV-1083)]$ gradle sonarqube --stacktrace

Configure project :
BRANCH: issues/SAV-1083
project version from Git: 0.4.0-SNAPSHOT

Task :sonarqube
Metric 'public_documented_api_density' is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Provided value is ignored.
Metric 'lines' is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Provided value is ignored.
Metric 'public_documented_api_density' is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Provided value is ignored.
Metric 'lines' is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Provided value is ignored.
Metric 'test_success_density' is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Provided value is ignored.
Coverage measure for metric 'lines_to_cover' should not be saved directly by a Sensor. Plugin should be updated to use SensorContext::newCoverage instead.
Coverage measure for metric 'uncovered_lines' should not be saved directly by a Sensor. Plugin should be updated to use SensorContext::newCoverage instead.
Coverage measure for metric 'coverage_line_hits_data' should not be saved directly by a Sensor. Plugin should be updated to use SensorContext::newCoverage instead.
Coverage measure for metric 'conditions_to_cover' should not be saved directly by a Sensor. Plugin should be updated to use SensorContext::newCoverage instead.
Coverage measure for metric 'uncovered_conditions' should not be saved directly by a Sensor. Plugin should be updated to use SensorContext::newCoverage instead.
Coverage measure for metric 'conditions_by_line' should not be saved directly by a Sensor. Plugin should be updated to use SensorContext::newCoverage instead.
Coverage measure for metric 'covered_conditions_by_line' should not be saved directly by a Sensor. Plugin should be updated to use SensorContext::newCoverage instead.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.

  ```
  Component can't be null
  ```
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:

  ```
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:242)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:95)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:235)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:224)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:121)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:102)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:96)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:612)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:567)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:96)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:57)
       at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:122)
       at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
       at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
       at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:253)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:95)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:170)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:44)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
       at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService$2.execute(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:124)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:116)
       at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:95)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
       at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:42)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:50)
       at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
       at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
       at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
       at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component can't be null
       at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122)
       at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.measure.internal.DefaultMeasure.on(DefaultMeasure.java:53)
       at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorStorage.saveMeasure(DefaultSensorStorage.java:244)
       at org.sonar.scanner.index.DefaultIndex.addMeasure(DefaultIndex.java:153)
       at org.sonar.scanner.deprecated.DeprecatedSensorContext.saveMeasure(DeprecatedSensorContext.java:127)
       at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoOverallSensor$OverallAnalyzer.saveMeasures(JaCoCoOverallSensor.java:101)
       at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.readExecutionData(AbstractAnalyzer.java:150)
       at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.AbstractAnalyzer.analyse(AbstractAnalyzer.java:114)
       at org.sonar.plugins.jacoco.JaCoCoOverallSensor.analyse(JaCoCoOverallSensor.java:80)
       at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:88)
       at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:82)
       at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:68)
       at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
       at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:179)
       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
       at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:261)
       at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:256)
       at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:254)
       at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:245)
       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
       at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
       at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
       at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
       at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:119)
       at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:116)
       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy528.execute(Unknown Source)
       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
       at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:99)
       at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:711)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:694)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
       at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:95)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
       at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
       ... 96 more
  ```

Comment: What version of SonarJava are you using? (Found in Administration -> System -> Update Center.)

Comment: SonarJava version 3.14

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to G. Ann asking me what version my SonarJava plugin was.

The installed SonarJava plugin was 3.14. When I upgraded to 4.12, the problem disappeared. Thanks G. Ann!